# Visual Studio пишет символ йены вместо слеша '\'

Tags: visual-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]В VS не могу вывести обратный слеш. Вместо него выводится символ японской йены.
Не смотря на то что отображается йена , функционал этот символ выполняет как слэш.
Кто знает решение данной проблемы ?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Японскую локаль у себя включали (чтобы в японские игры играть)?

Comment: Нет. Причем это проявляется ТОЛЬКО в VS. На других ресурсах в том числе и здесь оба слэша печатаются '/' '\'

Comment: Попробуйте сбросить горячие клавиши. Tools - Options - Environment - Keyboard - Reset

Comment: Сброс клавиш не помог

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решил.
Проблема в какой то степени банальна.Один из шрифтов отображает другой символ.
Возможно кому то поможет...[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот шрифт отображающий "йену"